# How to show all posts of the category in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, posts, query-posts

I have create a category by using Custom Post Type plugin, and now only the 5 most recent posts of the category are showing.
What I want is to show all posts for the category.
For examle, suppose I have movies category -  I want all movies in that category.
What code should I use and where?
I don't know much about the wordpress, so I would appreciate a step by step process.

Comment: Because I'm not a developer, I've tried and I'm now using "Content Views". You can use it to display category posts only. Great plugin!

Answer (score 13):

```
   <?php
    $args = array( 'category' => 7, 'post_type' =>  'post' ); 
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );    
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
    ?>  
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

just change the category id (number 7)
and change the post_type that was in the plugin

to learn more about post_type, see link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy to do it with wordpress. You have to understand that post are normally display within a "loop", a small code that repeat itself. You have to use one to do that.

```
<?php 
 $catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("NameOfTheCategory")); //change this
   foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
       <div>
             <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
             <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
       </div>
<?php  endforeach;?>
```

You should change the output to what fit your needs

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for accessing all post of specific category. In your category.php page use the spinet of code

```
$current_category = get_queried_object(); ////getting current category
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'our-services',// your post type,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $current_category->cat_ID // current category ID
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($the_query->have_posts()):
   while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();
    echo "<h2>".the_title()."</h2>";
    echo "<p>".the_content()."</p>";
endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from code someone else wrote, and which I benefitted from too long ago to know where it came from (if the person who originally wrote it is reading this, thanks again). It works for your request:

```
<?php
$catPost = get_posts('cat=888&posts_per_page=-1000');
   foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('name of your thumbnail'); ?>
  </a>

<h4>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a>
</h4>
<hr/ style="clear:both;">
<?php  endforeach;?>
```